# How does Excel's Workbook_Open() event actually work?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using an Excel file to operate a small business system and have noticed some quirks with the `Workbook_Open()` event. The file contains dozens of modules (including class modules representing business logic such as invoices and customers) and I have not been able to reproduce the issue with an MCVE but am hoping someone can help me learn something from this.

The setup is straightforward, the `Workbook_Open()` event in the `ThisWorkbook` object calls a sub named `Init` placed in a regular model called `Main`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Main.Init
End Sub
```

The `Init` sub in the `Main` module prints a start-up message to the immediate window and calls some other subs to initiate a couple of global variables to hold some data:

```
Public Sub Init()
    ' Called by ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open().
    Debug.Print "Initializing variables..."
    Debug.Print "The system contains:"
    Call Init_Items
End Sub

Public Sub Init_Items()
    ' This sub populates a collection of objects of a CInvoice class by looking 
    ' up data in an Invoices table (a VBA ListObject); it produces output
    ' similar to the following:
    Debug.Print "230 invoices."
End Sub
```

If the above code is placed in a sample file, it will print the following start-up message to the Immediate window when that file is opened:

```
Initialzing variables...
The system contains:
230 invoices.
```

This simple setup basically corresponds to the operational business file. However, when the business file is opened the **output is printed *twice* to the Immediate window.** To figure out what's going on, I placed a `Stop` in `Workbook_Open()`, in the hope that I could step through the code. To my surprise this revealed that the first iteration of the start-up message was written to the Immediate window even before the call to `Main.Init`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Stop   ' <--- The output produced by Main.Init is written to the 
           '      Immediate window twice, both before and after this Stop.
    Call Main.Init
End Sub
```

Moreover, `Workbook_Open()` also writes the number `3` to the Immediate window. This `3` is typically written after each iteration of the start-up message, but occasionally the first `3` is written before the first iteration of the start-up message and then after the second iteration. Sometimes it's written only once, after the first iteration of the start-up message but I have not noticed any pattern to this behavior.

This isn't really a big issue since the system is working properly but I'm curious to know what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried starting Workboo_Open manually and stepping through the code?

Comment: There are actually a number of events that are fired when a workbook opens. While I'm not necessarily saying that `WorkbookOpen` is called twice, there is a hierarchy and event sequence that you should be aware of. [This site](https://pixcels.nl/events-in-workbooks/) gives a good overview.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT, that is useful.

Comment: The two sets of messages are definitely coming from the same workbook?

Comment: @TimWilliams, yes indeed from the same workbook; I've experimented a bit with opening the file with and without other workbooks open, and with or without Excel already running, but the behavior is the same - with occasional exceptions concerning when the `3` appears, but with no apparent pattern.

Comment: By the way, I have observed this behavior for some time, at least a couple of months. The `3` used to be a `2`. It changed as I was developing the file by adding more class modules, but otherwise the file behaves nicely and as expected.